# Read all class name in the DOM, read the style values for those classes and add them inline to the element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a requirement to deliver my HTML content as email. As outlook doesnt understand all css class names, i plan to convert the css class into inline styles. The ID of the html elements are not standard . it would vary everytime. So i would like to read all the Class names in the HTML under the main DIV, go to the CSS file and read the style values of the class names and add them as inline style to the elements.

HTML:

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="line-height: 18px; margin: 0px;">
<div><span class="ms-rteFontFace-7 ms-rteFontSize-5" rtenodeid="3" style="font-family: Impact; font-size: 24pt;"><br></span></div>
<div rtenodeid="10"><span class="ms-rteFontFace-10 ms-rteFontSize-1" rtenodeid="3" >this is sample1​​</span></div>
<div rtenodeid="10"><span class="ms-rteFontFace-10 ms-rteFontSize-5" rtenodeid="3" >this is sample2​​</span></div>
<div rtenodeid="10"><span class="ms-rteFontFace-1 ms-rteFontSize-3" rtenodeid="3" >this is sample​​3</span></div>
<div rtenodeid="10"><span class="ms-rteFontFace-5 ms-rteFontSize-4" rtenodeid="3">this is sample​​4</span></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.ms-rteFontFace-1{"font-family":"tahoma"}
.ms-rteFontFace-2{"font-family":"georgia"}
.ms-rteFontFace-3{"font-family":"arial"}  etc

.ms-rteFontSize-1{"font-size":"11pt"} 
.ms-rteFontSize-2{"font-size":"12pt"} 
.ms-rteFontSize-3{"font-size":"13pt"}  etc
```

Comment: strongly recommend using a third party tool to do this for you. a google search for "css inliner" will give you several.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using this library https://github.com/Karl33to/jquery.inlineStyler . below is the code added to my js.

```
function addInlineStyles(){
var cssRules = {
    'propertyGroups': {
        'block': ['margin', 'padding'],
        'inline': ['color', 'font-size', 'font-family'],
        'headings': ['font-size', 'font-family' ]
    },
    'elementGroups': {
        'block': ['DIV', 'P', 'H1'],
        'inline': ['SPAN','P','DIV'],
        'headings': ['H1', 'H2', 'H3']
    }
}
$("#mainDiv").inlineStyler(cssRules);
}
```